Unable to Retrieve and Read .eml Attachments in Gmail Using Google Apps Script
I am facing an issue while using Google Apps Script to automate the retrieval of .eml file attachments from specific emails in my Gmail inbox. My script is designed to search for emails with a specific subject line, log the messages, and identify any .eml attachments present. However, despite confirming that the emails contain .eml files, my script does not seem to locate or read them properly.
I have added logging statements throughout the script to monitor the messages and attachments being processed, but I am not receiving any output related to .eml attachments. This leads me to believe that there may be an issue with how I am accessing or filtering the attachments.
I need assistance in troubleshooting this issue to ensure that I can effectively retrieve and read the contents of the .eml attachments from the targeted emails.
function findSpecificEmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"Your Email Subject Here"'); // Change the subject to match your email
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
      var message = messages[i][j];
      var attachments = message.getAttachments();
      
      for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        Logger.log('Found attachment: ' + attachment.getName() + ' of type ' + attachment.getContentType());
        
        if (attachment.getName().endsWith('.eml')) {
          var emlContent = attachment.getDataAsString();
          Logger.log('EML Content: ' + emlContent);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


FWIW, an . eml file is an electronic mail format or email saved in plain text.

I think that when the eml file message/rfc822 is attached to an email, it seems that when the email is retrieved by Gmail service (GmailApp), getAttachments() returns empty. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. If you want to retrieve the content of the email using your showing script, it can be retrieved by message.getBody(). But, in this case, the HTML content is retrieved.
If you want to retrieve the raw eml file as the attachment file, I guessed that Gmail API might be able to be used. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
Before you use this script, please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services.
function findSpecificEmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"Your Email Subject Here"'); // Change the subject to match your email
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
      var message = messages[i][j];

      // --- I modified the below script.
      const messageId = message.getId();
      const obj = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", messageId).payload.parts.find(e => e.body.attachmentId);
      if (obj) {
        const { filename, mimeType, body: { attachmentId } } = obj;
        const { data } = Gmail.Users.Messages.Attachments.get("me", messageId, attachmentId);
        Logger.log(`Found attachment: "${filename}" of type "${mimeType}"`);
        if (filename.endsWith('.eml')) {
          const emlContent = Utilities.newBlob(data).getDataAsString();
          Logger.log('EML Content: ' + emlContent);
        }
      }
      // ---

    }
  }
}

When this script is run, the message and the attachment file are retrieved by Gmail API. And, the attachment ID is searched. When the filename of the attachment file includes .eml, the content of the eml file is shown in the log.
References:

Method: users.messages.get
Method: users.messages.attachments.get

